# error: expected unqualified-id before 'else'

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have tried checking other answers already, but I still cannot find the answer. I am getting this error:

```
compilation info

prog.cpp:192:2: error: expected unqualified-id before 'else'
  else if (userInput == 3)
  ^
```

Here is the line of code:

```
else if (userInputSolveFor == "t")
        {
            cout << "You are solving for time." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "What is the acceleration (in m/s/s)?" << endl;
            cin >> acceleration;
            cout << "What is the initial velocity?" << endl;
            cin >> initialVelocity;
            cout << "What is the distance (in meters)?" << endl;
            cin >> deltaDistance;
            if (initialVelocity == 0)
            {
                cout << "The time is " << sqrt(deltaDistance - (0.5 * acceleration)) << setprecision(10) << " seconds." << endl;
            }
            else if (acceleration == 0)
            {
                cout << "The time is " << (deltaDistance / initialVelocity) << setprecision(10) << " seconds." << endl;
            }
            else 
            {
                cout << "The input you have entered is not valid." << endl;
            }
        }
    }
        else
        {
            cout << "The input you have entered is not valid." << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (userInput == 3)
    {
        cout << "You are using vf^2 = vi^2 + 2(a)(x)." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "What are you trying to solve for?" <<endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Use vf for final velocity (in m/s)." << endl;
        cout << "Use vi for initial velocity (in m/s)." << endl;
        cout << "Use a for acceleration." << endl;
        cout << "Use x for distance (in meters)." <<endl;
        cin >> userInputSolveFor;
        cout << endl;
```

Where line 192 is

```
else if (userInput == 3)
```

I don't know what to do. I have tried adding/removing "}" and I get 15+ errors when I change a single brace so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: If you're not using an editor / IDE which will help you keep code blocks consistently indented, you may want to take a look at [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) or something similar, which should help.

Comment: Proper indentation would help a ton.

Comment: Perhaps you have an extra `else cout << "The input you have . . .`

Comment: A good IDE will allow you to highlight matching brackets & solve problems like this easily (code-folding also helps).

Comment: Notepad++ highlights matching brackets when you put mouse cursor near one of them

Answer (score 0):

From this part of code it looks like you have too many closing brackets, reformat your code and check again.

edit: or too little opening brackets, anyway as in 1st answer proper formatting will help you.

Answer (score 0):

the second else statement of yours, doesn't belong there. cut it out and enter it after else if(userInput==3) block.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue...I had one too many brackets and I was missing a parenthesis. Thank you everybody for your help, I am still very new to coding and all the help is greatly appreciated. I am using Notepad++ as of now, and am trying to learn proper indentation before it becomes a bad habit. Again, thank you all. Detailed answer:

`}
else if (userInput == 3)` The } wasn't necessary, one too many

and was also missing a parenthesis in a further line of code, which accounted for 10+ errors. Thanks again!